# UIKitCore -[UIMoreListController .cxx_destruct]

Tags: swift, uikit

This problem does not occur to all users (approximately one in a thousand). I am getting a good number of crashes that are reported to Crashlytics. Only iPhone 14 Pro Max has this issue, and I have no idea how to replicate it.[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I recently encountered the same problem and solved it. You can check if there are too many view controllers inserted into the tab bar, which could cause an overflow of menu items beyond the screen's limits.